# PHPMailer ZIP all attachments

Tags: php, zip, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send attachments to email.

I have if statements such as:

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox1'])) {
   $mail->addAttachment('pdf/1.pdf');
   $name = "PDF 1";
}
if(isset($_POST['checkbox2'])) {
   $mail->addAttachment('pdf/2.pdf');
   $name = "PDF 2">
}
```

At the end for every checkbox selected I want to compress all attachments and put them in a zip instead of just sending one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not PHPMailer's job to do that. [Zip the files first](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php), then attach them:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "./files.zip";
$hasfiles = false;

if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}

if(isset($_POST['checkbox1'])) {
    $zip->addFile('pdf/1.pdf');
    $hasfiles = true;
}
if(isset($_POST['checkbox2'])) {
    $zip->addFile('pdf/2.pdf');
    $hasfiles = true;
}

$zip->close();

if ($hasfiles) {
    $mail->addAttachment($filename);
}
```

Comment: This works now but it's sending every file even if it's not selected. for example if i select checkbox one, it's sending the file of checkbox one and two, perhaps i have to generate different zip files? if so how would i do this?

Comment: I fixed this by just unlinking the zip file after the email is sent, thanks.